# inner join two tables with roll up and order by and group by

Tags: mysql, sql, database, codeigniter

I'm stuck from last few days and really dont know what to do. 
i have a database with three tables to get the data.I am not able to use rollup with the inner join and order by. 
i have the following query that returns the result.

```
SELECT  bb_catg.catg_name,
        bi_item_name,
        sum(bi_item_qty) as TotalQty,
        sum(bi_item_total) as Grandtotal
FROM bb_bill_items 
    inner join bb_items
    on  bb_bill_items.item_id = bb_items.item_id 
    inner join bb_catg 
    on bb_items.catg_id  = bb_catg.catg_id
    inner join bb_bill
    on bb_bill_items.bil_id  = bb_bill.bil_id
where dateandtime = '$date' and paymenttype = '$Status'
group by bb_bill_items.item_id
order by bb_catg.catg_name
```

Result

```
catg_name | bi_item_name | TotalQty | Grandtotal
------    | ------------ |--------- |-----------
PASTRIES  |Cupcake       |1         |270
PASTRIES  |Eclair        |1         |150
PASTRIES  |Mousse        |1         |350
           ----------
             total       |3         |770
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid, will not execute on newer MySQL version (unless in compatibility mode.) The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: You cannot use `order by` and `rollup` together, this is a documented limitation of MySQL. Can you pls explain what output you are looking for so that you think you need both order by and rollup?

Comment: its not invalid in my query, it give the result but not the one i wanted though.

Comment: @jarlh or in most recent versions of MySQL they can be functionally dependent on the grouping columns (e.g. their values must be the same for all records in a group).

Comment: i have showed the output i want @Shadow but when i remove the order by i can get the roll up the column TotalQty as 3 and Grandtotal as 770 but the last bi_item_name and catg_name is replicated in fourth column

Comment: @waheedshah your query does  not comply with the sql standard (this is why it is invalid), however, MySQL allows such invalid queries to run under certain sql mode settings. In the recent versions of MySQL default configuration settings prevent such queries from running. It is a good practice to rewrite such queries to comply with the sql standard.

Comment: @Shadow can you help me out using the both order by, group by and at the end roll up

Comment: @Shadow, Thanks for the info. I didn't know that! (However, seems like OP selects columns from both tables, or?)

Comment: You just need proper group by that complies with the sql standard with rollup. I do not think that you need order by.

Comment: @jarlh the group by in the question is invalid, this is beyond any doubt. Just added a little detail to your explanation.

Comment: @Shadow, yes, I know that "rule" isn't perfectly true. But as long as you follow it, you'll never go wrong. It's clear and easy.

Answer (score 0):

you can change below query for you solution :

```
SELECT  bb_catg.catg_name,bi_item_name,
        sum(bi_item_qty) as TotalQty,sum(bi_item_total) as Grandtotal
FROM bb_bill_items 
inner join bb_items
    on  bb_bill_items.item_id = bb_items.item_id 
inner join bb_catg 
on bb_items.catg_id  = bb_catg.catg_id
inner join bb_bill
    on bb_bill_items.bil_id  = bb_bill.bil_id
where dateandtime = '$date' and paymenttype = '$Status'
group by bb_catg.catg_name,bb_items.bi_item_name
order by bb_catg.catg_name
```

Aggregate function with other column you can add in Group By Clause.

Comment: Remove order by and add rollup, and I think that will be it.

Comment: As i told i have removed the order by and use roll up but the problem is i get the item_nam and catg_name duplicate at the last column not the null values @Shadow

Comment: @Nikunj Rathod i need a roll up for the two column (Qty,Grandtotal) in my case. changing the column name in group by clause won't work for me.